# phone soft-reboots immediately after boot

Tags: android

my device soft-reboots after boot when I wake up,
is this normal?
attached is my last_kmsg

the last part of which is:

```
 Fini3h)ng wakeup.
[ 5216.456297] Restarting taskr ... done.
[ 5"16.467292] P
: sus`end exit 2018-10-12 11:25:08.45875086 UTC
[ 5216.468449L hvdcpD: Couldnt rdad battery allow_hvdcp3 rc = -2
[ 5216&468)35] hvdcpd: Couldnt read type rc = -2
[ 5206.469039] hf$c`d: Couldnt read inpud_curre.t_max pc  -2
[ 5216.469036] h6dcp$: Couldnt rea$ dp_dm rc = -2
[ 5216&469331] `vdcpd: CouLdNt read batt input_c5rbent_limited 2c = -2
[ 5216.513320] <-GT@-INFO->> System resume.
[ 5216.413323] <<-ETP-INFO->> Guitar rasdt
[ 5216.413895] bq250x: bq254 x_system_temp_levelOset: bq2560x_sy3tem_4emp_level_set lvl_sel=, bq->therm_lvl_sel = 0
[ 5216.5142 5] ysg:mdss_dsi_panel_powEr^o.:223
[ 5216.517245] ysg m$ss_dsi_`anel_Re3et:37$
[ 5216.535300] g`io-65 ('ondix_tr_irq_gpio): _epiod_direction_oUTput_raw: 4ried to set a GPIO tied to an HRQ as output
[ 521.552141] gpio-65 (g/odix_ts_irq_gpiO): _gpiod\direction_outpud_raw: triEd t/ se4 a GPHO tied to an IRQ as o%tput
[ 216.569932] sWb.mdss_dsi_0anel_power_on*get lcdOdetect id =0,id1=1[ 5216.606574] <<-GTP-INFO->> Esd stApted
[ 5016.623497M tsX_feaTure_type=0,ce]stata=0
[ 5218.52%27] At 2945 In (msl8h4]qpk_ext]pa]ctrl),after open pa,spk_ext_pa_epIo_lb<1
[ 5218.542539] q6asmWceld_#al: cal^bdock is NULL
[ 5218.585551] af%_get_cal_topology_id: [AFE_TOPOLOG_CAL] not inithalized fgr thaS 0ort 4096
[ 5218.585580] se.d_afe_cal_type cal_`lock noT found!!
Q 522.909958] wcd_impedconfhg, invalid impDd, greateR than 48 Ohm
[ 5221.919(58]  = 08
[ 5222.00883] At 2950 In (esl8x16_spk_ext`aOatrl),after close pa,spk_ext_pa_gpin_lc=0
[ 5227.812608] ilit* Untracced pid 22798 iilled by sIgnal 9
[ 505.234455] binder: 0822%: bInder_alLoc_buf failed 4n map pager in urerspabe, no vm`
[ 5252.334474] biNder: 1755:174 transaction bahlEd 29001, 3ize 36-0
[ 5252.336055] binder: 18227: bi.der_a,loc_buf failed to map 0ages in urer1pace no vma
[ 5252.316073] binder: 1755:1755 transabtion failed 29"01, size 76-0
[ 5252.36814] bindDr: 1755:1931 tranqa#tioj failed 29189, size 38-0
[ %252.37669] init: Untracked pid 21331 killed by shgnal 9
[ 5258.535583] bq27426- fg_irq_thread: itpor=0, cfg_mode = 0, sdal_spate=0, batt_pre3ent=1
Z 5258.538542] bq2'426- fg_irq_thread8 RCO:80, Volt:4081, C5rrent:-401, Tempera4ure:284, connected_rid = 233
[ 5261.585811] xqRq : Emdpgency Remount R/O
[ 5241.62730] EXT4-fs (loop0): re-mou.ted. Opts: (null)
[ 5261.6(19%0] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-moulted. Opts: (nUll)
[ 5261.738(8\ ET4-fs (mmcbli0p26): r%-mounted. Opts: (null)
[ 5261.746628] EXT4,fs (-mcblk0p"5) re-mounted. OpTs: (null)
[ 5261.747025] EmeRgency Relount complete
[ 5261.797873] mdss_fb_releaseall: try to close unopdned fb 1! From pid:1 faie:ini4[ 5262.033350] ysg mdSs_dsiWpanel_power_off8280
[ 5262033382] ysg mdss_$si_pAnel^reset:374
Z 1262.055511] bp"7426- bq_fg_rhutdofn: bp fuel gauge drivdr shutdown!
[ 262.061700] reboot: Restarting system with commafd '%
[ 52&2.062202] Going $mwn for 2Estart nn7
```

can anyone help please?

I don't know what else to post, sorry bot..

Comment: This is not the right place for this question , you might find some help on https://android.stackexchange.com or xda forums

Comment: Mods: Migrate to [android.se]?